# Discord.js delete thread

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im working on a discord bot that works with threads

but I ran into an issue

In certain cases id like the bot to delete a thread but there is no documentation on deleting threads. I saw stuff about locking threads but theres nothing about directly deleting them

Comment: Doubt you didn't find anything, but anyways the first result when I searched `discordjs delete threads` was this page: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/threads.html#creating-and-deleting-threads

Answer (score 0):

Alright, heres the solution:

```
await ex_thread.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is in the documentation of discord.js :

https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/threads.html#thread-related-gateway-events
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ThreadChannel?scrollTo=delete

Comment: It is better to include the actual answer here if you can and not just links to a document(s) as these can become outdated and loose relevance to the question.